# Pass value of a function to a global variable

Tags: javascript

In html, I have

```
 <form id="form">
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="north" onClick="input(value)">north<br>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="east" onClick="input(value)" >east<br>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="west" onClick="input(value)">west<br>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="south" onClick="input(value)">south
</form>
```

And the way I thought of fetching selected radio is like,

```
 var input=function(x)
    {
           console.log(x);
     }
```

I actually first coded like,

```
 var input="north";
    var dd=function(x)
    {
       if(input==null)
       {
          return direction.map(function (c) {

        return data.map(function (d) {

            //console.log(d[c]);
                 return {x: d.month, y: d[c]};
             })    
         })
         }

            else{
                 return data.map(function (d) {
                   return {x: d.month , y : d[input]};
               }}

    }
    var dataIntermediate=dd(input);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataIntermediate));
```

But now I actually need to take the value of input to this function onclick and I am confused how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: change input(value) to input(this.value) and ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## change input(value) to input(this.value) and ready

```js
var global;

var input = function(x) {
    global = x;
    console.log(x);
};

// Checking the global variable in realTime
setInterval(function(){
  document.querySelector("#globalVariableValue").innerText = global;
},10);
```

```html
<form id="form">
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="north" onClick="input(this.value)">north<br>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="east" onClick="input(this.value)" >east<br>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="west" onClick="input(this.value)">west<br>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="south" onClick="input(this.value)">south
</form>

<br />

<span id="globalVariableValue"></span>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get console.log(global) as  the corresponding value outside the function??

Comment: Because, on load, global would be assigned to zero even before an action is taken

Comment: Sure. Just execute the funcions with the correct sequence. after the action  the global value change.

Comment: I coded like,


var global;

var input = function(x) {
    global = x;
    console.log(global);
};
console.log("main"+global);

What happens is like, on page load,
i get output as
mainundefined

Later on selection in radio,
console.log("main"+global) doesn't get called at all. I still don't get why

Comment: Thanks for the idea of set interval!

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use inline HTML event handling attributes (`onclick`, etc.) as they create "spaghetti code", create anonymous global functions that modify the `this` binding and don't follow the **[W3C DOM Event Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#introduction-to-dom-events)**

Here's all you need to get the value of a radio button and then pass that value somewhere:

```js
var radVal = null;

// Once the DOM is ready...
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Get all the radiobuttons
  var btns = document.querySelectorAll("[name=stack]");
  
  // Loop through them
  for(var i =0; i < btns.length; ++i){
    
      // Set up a click event handling callback function
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(evt){
        // That grabs the value from the clicked button
        radVal = evt.target.value;
        
        // You can call another function from here, but if that other function
        // needs the value, you don't need to pass it because you just set it
        // into a variable (radVal) which has a higher scope than this function
        foo();
        
        // Or, you can not call another function from here and just call the 
        // other function when you need to, but you will need to make sure that
        // this happens AFTER one of the radio buttons were clicked, otherwise
        // radVal will still be null
      });
  }
 
  function foo(){
    // Since this function can be called at any time, we should check to make
    // sure that one of the radio buttons has first been clicked.
    if(radVal){
      // radVal is not null, so a radio button was clicked
      console.log("foo says value is: " + radVal);
    } else {
      // radVal is still null so no button has been clicked yet
      console.log("foo says no button was clicked");      
    }
  }
  
  // This will show the else message because this is being called
  // before the radio buttons have been clicked
  foo();  
  


});
```

```html
 <form id="form">
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="north">north<br>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="east">east<br>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="west">west<br>
        <input type="radio" name="stack" value="south">south
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this but radVal remained null outside the function

Comment: If you kept the "var radVal" outside of "input" and you don't call your second function before you've selected a radio button, that would not happen.

Answer (score 0):

you need to start a function, after that specify an "ID" for the input and that will make the selection of vaule and running the function accurate.

for example:

```
    function something(){

if(document.getElementById('north').checked) {
      //do something
 } else {
      // do something else
 }
```

the input looks like

```
<input type="radio" id="north" name="stack" value="north" onClick="functionName(this.value)">north<br>
```

Comment: I don't wanna disturb the method as of now.